# Passing data from service to modal component in Angular

Tags: angular, service, modal-dialog

I'm new in Angular Programming. I'm trying to pass data from service to my modal component, but an empty modal is displayed first, and the data comes later (I can see data in console.log or when I open a modal second time). Here is my code:

**geoname.service.ts**

```
export class GeonameService {

  private geonames: Geoname[] = [];
  private geonamesUpdated = new Subject<Geoname[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCity(searchText: string, country: string) {
    const queryParams = `?apikey=` + environment.opendataKey + `&dataset=xxxxx&rows=50&sort=place_name&q=` + searchText + `&refine.country_code=` + country;
    this.http
      .get(environment.opendataUrl + queryParams)
      .pipe(
        map(geonameData => {
          return geonameData[`records`].map(data => {
            return {
              country: data.fields.country_code,
              zipcode: data.fields.postal_code,
              place: data.fields.place_name,
              admin: data.fields.admin_name2,
              latitude: data.fields.latitude,
              longitude: data.fields.longitude
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedGeonameData => {
        this.geonames = transformedGeonameData;
        this.geonamesUpdated.next([...this.geonames]);
      });
  }

  getGeocodeListener() {
    return this.geonamesUpdated.asObservable();
  }

}
```

**map-view.component.ts**

```
export class MapViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('searchCityInput', { static: false }) searchCityInput: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('countrySelect', { static: false }) countrySelect: ElementRef;

  private geonames: Geoname[] = [];

  constructor(private basicService: BasicService, private geonameService: GeonameService, private modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.geonameService.getGeocodeListener().subscribe(data => {
      this.geonames = data;
    });
  }

  searchCity() {
    this.geonameService.getCity(this.searchCityInput.nativeElement.value, this.countrySelect.nativeElement.value);
    this.modalService.showGeonameModal(this.geonames);
  }

}
```

I know that this is asynchronous and the code is not executed in turn. Apart from that, please check the rest of my code if I'm programming correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid subscribing in your service, and instead just subscribe from your component. This will allow you to reuse this code and give your component more control over what happens when the request is done.

```
getCity(searchText: string, country: string) {
    const queryParams = `?apikey=` + environment.opendataKey + `&dataset=xxxxx&rows=50&sort=place_name&q=` + searchText + `&refine.country_code=` + country;
    return this.http.get(environment.opendataUrl + queryParams).pipe(
        map(geonameData => {
            return geonameData[`records`].map(data => {
                return {
                    country: data.fields.country_code,
                    zipcode: data.fields.postal_code,
                    place: data.fields.place_name,
                    admin: data.fields.admin_name2,
                    latitude: data.fields.latitude,
                    longitude: data.fields.longitude
                };
            });
        })
    );
}
```

Then all you have to do is open the modal when the request is complete:

```
searchCity() {
    this.geonameService.getCity(this.searchCityInput.nativeElement.value, this.countrySelect.nativeElement.value).subscribe((geoNames) => {
        this.modalService.showGeonameModal(geoNames);
    });
}
```

Unless you are sharing this data among other subscribers, you probably don't need to use a Subject() at all.